# How to detect the missing dynamic arguments in String.Format()

Tags: c#, string, string.format

```
string myString = string.Format("{0}{1}", "foo");
```

This compiles but fails at runtime. I know why, don't worry. Anyone knows of a macro or a tool that would check my whole solution to find every occurrence of this... distraction while coding? Something simple that only checks if the expression is not a variable would suffice. It's probably doable with FxCop or StyleCop, but the simpler the better :-D

Thanks

Comment: You write unit tests to flush out bugs like these.  And many more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) from jetbrains
..
[image]

Comment: In the past, I tried ReSharper, but not for too long since I was just beginning coding. Today, I reinstalled the trial and I really liked it! Thanks for this suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I use Visual Studio 2010 (Premium) and (menu) Analyze > Run Code analysis does the trick (and many many others). I don't know if this works in other VS versions.

Comment: Home, I got a VS version I bought cheap when I was in university so it has that feature, but sadly, I can't use VS2010 yet at my workplace, they haven't upgraded yet. I like this answer though since it's so simple, yet working!